# Static list not updating when I call the function that does so

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, parsing, static, static-variables

I'm kind of new to Unity, and I'm trying to make a visual novel.
I have one class with my static variable lines, which is a list of lines of dialogue. I have a second class with method LoadDialogue() that reads a text file and adds the lines of dialogue to the static variable lines. I have a third class that calls LoadDialogue(), gets a line of dialogue from the static variable, and displays it when I click the mouse button.

When I run the program and press the mouse button, I get an ArgumentOutOfRangeException. I know this is because the list that I am trying to get a line of dialogue from is empty, but I don't know why it is empty. I don't know what else to try because I am incredibly unfamiliar with both the language and the engine.

Here is my code for my variable class (MyTypes is a separate class that I used to create a struct and some enums):

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class V : MonoBehaviour{

    public static List<MyTypes.DialogueLine> lines;
    public static MyTypes.TimeOfDay time;

    public static int day;
    public static int credits;

}
```

Here is the code for my dialogue parsing class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System.IO;

public class ParseDialogue : MonoBehaviour {
    public void LoadDialogue() {
        string fileName = "Assets/Resources/Dialogue/";
        fileName += V.time.ToString();
        fileName += V.day.ToString();
        fileName += ".txt";

        V.lines = new List<MyTypes.DialogueLine>();
        ReadDialogue(fileName);
    }

    public void ReadDialogue(string fileName){
        string line = "New Line";
        StreamReader reader = null;

        try {
            using(reader = new StreamReader(fileName)){
                do {
                    line = reader.ReadLine();
                    string[] content = line.Split('|');
                    Enum.TryParse<MyTypes.DisplayPosition>(content[3], out MyTypes.DisplayPosition position);
                    MyTypes.DialogueLine newLine = new MyTypes.DialogueLine(content[0], content[1], position, int.Parse(content[2]));
                    V.lines.Add(newLine);
                } while (line != null);
                reader.Close();
            }
        } catch (Exception e){
            Console.WriteLine("The file could not be read.");
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the code for the class that displays dialogue (Parser is the empty object I created to put the ParseDialogue script into):

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class DisplayDialogue : MonoBehaviour {
    ParseDialogue parser;

    public string dialogue;
    int lineNum;

    public GUIStyle custom;

    void Start() {
        parser = GameObject.Find("Parser").GetComponent<ParseDialogue>();
        parser.LoadDialogue();

        dialogue = "";
        lineNum = 0;
    }

    void Update() {
        if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) || Input.GetKey("space")) {
            dialogue = V.lines[lineNum].getLine();
            lineNum++;
        }
    }

    void OnGUI() {
        dialogue = GUI.TextField(new Rect(25, 400, 300, 200), dialogue, custom);
    }
}
```

If you could help me out I'd really, really appreciate it!

**EDIT:** I solved the problem. Turns out the issue was that I had switched content[3] with content[2].

Comment: could you add Debug.Log(lineNum + ":" + V.lines.Count)  just after Input.GetMouseButton(0) and show the last value displayed before crash.. ans say me how lines have you in your file

Comment: I just tried it, and I got 0.

Comment: so you havent loaded your List.. you have a problem in your loader..check if you have records after loading line. I suggest you to show your file txt and explain what you want to trap in it..

Comment: Sorry for the late reply! I did some research and I'm wondering if the issue could be that my ReadDialogue() method isn't static? If that's not the case, I'll get back to you tomorrow since I've put my code away for the night.